# Same query taking different amounts of time to execute

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

### Table Details

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE foldertable

CREATE TABLE `foldertable` (
 `serverToken` bigint(1) NOT NULL,
 `folderName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `folderid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `RootFolderPath` longtext NOT NULL,
 `createdTime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `LastEdited` datetime NOT NULL,
 `RootFolderPreviewPath` longtext NOT NULL,
 `userFolderPathName` text NOT NULL,
 `starred` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `trashed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`folderid`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `serverToken` (`serverToken`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

### Engine status

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS

=====================================
2021-05-16 23:28:11 0x4228 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 25 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 7 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 2720 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 2727
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 43
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 48
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 100, OS waits 32
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 774, OS waits 5
RW-sx spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
Spin rounds per wait: 100.00 RW-shared, 774.00 RW-excl, 0.00 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 28244
Purge done for trx's n:o < 28243 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 25
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 283682528964920, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 283682528960704, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: native aio handle (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: native aio handle (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: native aio handle (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: native aio handle (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: native aio handle (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: native aio handle (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: native aio handle (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: native aio handle (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: native aio handle (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: native aio handle (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
479 OS file reads, 293 OS file writes, 95 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 0.00 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 11444640
Log flushed up to   11444640
Pages flushed up to 11444640
Last checkpoint at  11444631
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
65 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 33554432
Dictionary memory allocated 41472
Buffer pool size   1002
Free buffers       746
Database pages     256
Old database pages 0
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 335, created 142, written 225
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 256, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=11768, Main thread ID=10680, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 3, updated 0, deleted 0, read 146
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 1.08 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

### Points to note

I am always executing second query while first transaction is **running**. The `sleep(10)` is there intentionally. The `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is used as an alternative to an `update` statement. Till now the table is totally empty.

As the session progress the data will be inserted as given below. Nothing has happened at the back of the stage.

### Tests

#### First session

First statement

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($conn);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM foldertable where serverToken  = 1234567 FOR  UPDATE" ;
mysqli_query($conn , $sql) ;
echo (mysqli_error($conn)) ;
echo(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)) ;
sleep (10);
mysqli_commit($conn) ;
```

Second statement

```
INSERT INTO `foldertable`(
    `serverToken`,
    `folderName`,
    `folderid`,
    `RootFolderPath`,
    `createdTime`,
    `LastEdited`,
    `RootFolderPreviewPath`,
    `userFolderPathName`,
    `starred`,
    `trashed`
)
VALUES(
    12345,
    '',
    'ABCDE',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    ''
);
```

Result:

```
1 row inserted. (Query took 9.4569 seconds.)
```

#### Second session

First statement

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($conn);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM foldertable where serverToken  = 1234567 FOR  UPDATE" ;
mysqli_query($conn , $sql) ;
echo (mysqli_error($conn)) ;
echo(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)) ;
sleep (10);
mysqli_commit($conn) ;
```

Second statement

```
INSERT INTO `foldertable`(
    `serverToken`,
    `folderName`,
    `folderid`,
    `RootFolderPath`,
    `createdTime`,
    `LastEdited`,
    `RootFolderPreviewPath`,
    `userFolderPathName`,
    `starred`,
    `trashed`
)
VALUES(
    12345,
    '',
    'ABCDEf',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    ''
);
```

Result:

```
1 row inserted. (Query took 9.4569 seconds.)
```

#### Third session

First statement

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($conn);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM foldertable where serverToken  = 1234567 FOR  UPDATE" ;
mysqli_query($conn , $sql) ;
echo (mysqli_error($conn)) ;
echo(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)) ;
sleep (10);
mysqli_commit($conn) ;
```

Second statement

```
INSERT INTO `foldertable`(
    `serverToken`,
    `folderName`,
    `folderid`,
    `RootFolderPath`,
    `createdTime`,
    `LastEdited`,
    `RootFolderPreviewPath`,
    `userFolderPathName`,
    `starred`,
    `trashed`
)
VALUES(
    1234567,
    '',
    'ABCDEfg',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    ''
);
```

Result:

```
1 row inserted. (Query took 9.4569 seconds.)
```

#### Fourth session

First statement

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($conn);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM foldertable where serverToken  = 1234567 FOR  UPDATE" ;
mysqli_query($conn , $sql) ;
echo (mysqli_error($conn)) ;
echo(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)) ;
sleep (10);
mysqli_commit($conn) ;
```

Second statement

```
INSERT INTO `foldertable`( `serverToken`, `folderName`, `folderid`, `RootFolderPath`, `createdTime`, `LastEdited`, `RootFolderPreviewPath`, `userFolderPathName`, `starred`, `trashed` ) VALUES( 123, '', 'ABCDEfgh', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' )
```

Result:

```
1 row inserted. (Query took 0.0073 seconds.)
```

#### Fifth session

First statement

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($conn);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM foldertable where serverToken  = 1234567 FOR  UPDATE" ;
mysqli_query($conn , $sql) ;
echo (mysqli_error($conn)) ;
echo(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)) ;
sleep (10);
mysqli_commit($conn) ;
```

Second statement

```
INSERT INTO `foldertable`( `serverToken`, `folderName`, `folderid`, `RootFolderPath`, `createdTime`, `LastEdited`, `RootFolderPreviewPath`, `userFolderPathName`, `starred`, `trashed` ) VALUES( 1235465, '', 'ABCEfgh', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' )
```

Result:

```
 1 row inserted. (Query took 9.5040 seconds.)
```

#### Sixth session

First statement

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($conn);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM foldertable where serverToken  = 1234567 FOR  UPDATE" ;
mysqli_query($conn , $sql) ;
echo (mysqli_error($conn)) ;
echo(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)) ;
sleep (10);
mysqli_commit($conn) ;
```

Second statement

```
INSERT INTO `foldertable`(
    `serverToken`,
    `folderName`,
    `folderid`,
    `RootFolderPath`,
    `createdTime`,
    `LastEdited`,
    `RootFolderPreviewPath`,
    `userFolderPathName`,
    `starred`,
    `trashed`
)
VALUES(
    1235465,
    '',
    'ABCEfghi',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    ''
);
```

Result:

```
1 row inserted. (Query took 0.0087 seconds.)
```

---

I am quite new to MySQL . I am using xamp for testing, phpmyadmin for queries, and postman for transaction API.

How can I understand this strange behaviour?

**Summary**

```
where serverToken  = 1234567 FOR  UPDATE  -- Session 1, all cases

Session 2:
12345,   'ABCDE',    First
12345,   'ABCDEf',   Second
1234567, 'ABCDEfg',  Third
123, '', 'ABCDEfgh'  Fourth --fast
1235465, 'ABCEfgh'   Fifth
1235465, 'ABCEfghi', Sixth -- fast
```

### Final Image

[image]

Comment: What behaviour are you considering strange? Note: Don't add a unique index the same as the PK, its not needed. Don't do `SELECT  ... FOR UPDATE` unless you need to do an update.

Comment: SELECT FOR UPDATE is used as an alternative of UPDATE . STRANGE IS EXECUTION TIME OF EACH INSERT STATEMENT

Comment: Your code declares two SQL strings but then executes only the second one.  Was this an oversight?  Please fix.

Comment: `SELECT FOR UPDATE` says "I might change this row(s); please keep away from them."

Comment: How many rows in the table?  Are `ABCEfg` and `ABCEfghi` consecutive in the index?  If so, insert a row between them (eg `ABCEfgh`), then see if you still have the problem.  (This is to see if there is a "gap lock" involved.  Also, provide `SHOW ENGINE=innodb STATUS` for more info.

Comment: In the table, what rows are adjacent to `1234567`.  (Just show serverToken and folderId, like I did in the Summary I added.)

Comment: ya , you have already summarized the whole process Thanks .  Others are just empty . Okay I am posting the final table Image .

Comment: Is anyone going to help me